# Upon Redirect of Form Submission within iFrame jQuery Not Detecting Updated Src Attribute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

So I have an iframe located on the page /profile/settings/index.php, i dont want my users to move away from /profile/settings/index.php while changing their settings.

The settings page automatically loads iframe-home.php. i then click on change name and it loads update.php. i then submit the form (which the action='') to submit back on itself. after updating the name, it redirects to iframe-home.php, but as you can see on the console, its still saying update.php... Heres a video of what this paragraph is about.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjALpZkmgWs&feature=youtu.be

So here's the iFrame:

```
<iframe src="iframe-home.php" id="settings-iframe" onload="onLoadHandler();" name="settings-iframe">
</iframe>
```

Whenever the page "update.php" is loaded within this iframe, there is a form on that page. Upon submission of that form, a `header()` Location function is called in php and the iframe is then redirected to iframe-home.php (upon successful validation, etc etc). However upon a `console.log()` the iframe src attribute is not being updated. The console.log is saying that i'm still on update.php and not iframe-home.php. This is a problem if i want to do something along the lines of:

```
function onLoadHandler() {
    var $location = $("#settings-iframe").attr("src");
    switch($location) {
        case "iframe-home.php":
            console.log($location);
            activateHome();
        break;
        case "changepassword.php":
            console.log($location);
            activatePassword();
        break;
        case "update.php":
            console.log($location);
            activateName();
        break;

    }
}
```

Not sure what code you need to see for this. I can't really abstract the code as i'm using about 10 different classes spread over two different programming languages.

The activate functions are changing css code. I've tested these functions and they work as indented. activateX() highlights the navigation link of the "active" page thats loaded in the iFrame.

I'm just trying to figure out how to force the iframe to reload the src attribute upon a header location redirect, or at least grab the correct src attribute. Why is the iframe telling me that i'm on update.php, when the page thats loaded it iframe-home.php...

Comment: xy problem, why do you need iframes?

Comment: I'm using iframes to load different pages without leaving /profile/settings/ page.

Comment: have you tried adding a unique id for each iframe page and getting that with jquery/javascript?

Comment: I already am doing that with my click listeners: `// Add the Click Listeners for the buttons
$("#home").on("click", function() {
 activateHome();
 $("#settings-iframe").attr("src", "iframe-home.php");
});
$("#password").on("click", function() {
 activatePassword();
 $("#settings-iframe").attr("src", "changepassword.php");
});
$("#name").on("click", function() {
 activateName();
 $("#settings-iframe").attr("src", "update.php");
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:- Full jQuery solution

`<iframe id="settings-iframe" name="settings-iframe"></iframe>`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe#settings-iframe').on('load', function() {
    // var location = this.contentWindow.location.href;
    var location = this.contentWindow.location.href.substr(this.contentWindow.location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    console.log('location : ', location);
    switch (location) {
        case "iframe-home.php":
        console.log(location);
        activateHome();
        break;
      case "changepassword.php":
        console.log(location);
        activatePassword();
        break;
      case "update.php":
        console.log(location);
        activateName();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

OLD:
Try this :-
 `var $location = this.contentWindow.location`

Comment: Code now reads: `function onLoadHandler() {
 var $location = this.contentWindow.location;` and i'm getting an error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined
    at onLoadHandler (index.js:6)
    at HTMLIFrameElement.onload ((index):101)

Comment: I am posting a video here (editing the question) for you to see whats going on. This video was done with you updated code.

Comment: There was  a small issue in my code, we need to use `this.contentWindow.location.href` not jquery attr for location. please check the result of console.log and and change your switch function according to that because `this.contentWindow.location.href` gives the full url. I have corrected the code and i hope you can modify the switch function to match new location(full url not just file name)

Comment: THIS WORKS! However, if i hard code this URL(http://localhost/Makoto/profile/settings/iframe-home.php) that has localhost as my host... i'm going to have issues when i deploy onto my server (myurl.com). So now that we know this works. How do we go about turning it into a deploy friendly piece of code?

Comment: Thanks for your help, still trying to figure out how to make this code deploy ready.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is now deploy ready. I'll be sure to reference this post in my Javascript code! Thank you so much for your help!