# Making Javascript Code Deploy Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make this code deploy ready. I can't hard code these URL's in but for some reason any other way of coding this, breaks. Reference this question here: [Upon Redirect of Form Submission within iFrame jQuery Not Detecting Updated Src Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771951/upon-redirect-of-form-submission-within-iframe-jquery-not-detecting-updated-src/44772165)

I basically need to have the switch check if the location CONTAINS the page name after 'settings/' i.e. iframe-home.php, update.php, or changepassword.php. I think thats how i fix this issue? But i'm not sure how. (Hope that makes sense)

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('iframe#settings-iframe').on('load', function() {
    var location = this.contentWindow.location.href;
    console.log('location : ', location);
    switch (location) {
        case "http://localhost/Makoto/profile/settings/iframe-home.php":
        console.log(location);
        activateHome();
        break;
      case "http://localhost/Makoto/profile/settings/changepassword.php":
        console.log(location);
        activatePassword();
        break;
      case "http://localhost/Makoto/profile/settings/update.php":
        console.log(location);
        activateName();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be alot easier to add different code to each page instead of adding it to all pages and just executing some of it? That way if you are on update.php-page you can just execute the code and not worry what code needs to be executed.

Comment: @Esko What if `iframe` has dynamic URL?

Answer (score 0):

*Note* I assume that you want dynamically check path without host part.

Create new link element, set `href` to `location`, compare it to `pathname`

```js
// replace with this.contentWindow.location.href
var url = "http://localhost/Makoto/profile/settings/iframe-home.php";

/**
 * http://localhost/Makoto/profile/settings/iframe-home.php
 * will return /Makoto/profile/settings/iframe-home.php
 */
var link = $('<a>', {
  href: url
})[0].pathname;

var parts = link.split('/');
var file = parts[parts.length - 1];

console.log(file);

switch (file) {
  case "iframe-home.php":
    activateHome();
    break;
  case "changepassword.php":
    activatePassword();
    break;
  case "update.php":
    activateName();
    break;
}

function activateHome() {console.log('Activating home');}
function activatePassword() {console.log('Activating password');}
function activateName() {console.log('Activating name');}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```